# spass object index is not a member of package views.html

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
git clone https://github.com/spass/spass.git
```

Then imported project (`sbt`) into `intellij`.

When I run `Rebuild Project` I get:

```
app/io/spass/controllers/Application.scala
Error:(9, 19) object index is not a member of package views.html
    Ok(views.html.index())
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
                  ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the folders and made the `target` not excluded, deleted the content of said folder, and run `sbt compile` from the command line.